# How to Get/Share/Update GEO Location using GeckoFX 45 VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, browser-automation, geckofx

I'm facing a problem. I have been trying to Fix it for 3 days. I need to Get/Share/Update the GEO Location through [GeckoFX 45](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geckofx45/45.0.34). I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304380/gecko-for-windows-forms-and-geolocation-how-to-accept-request-for-share-my-loca) before asking here but It does not make sense.

**Is there any working solution available? Please.**

Thank you.

Comment: So is the problem you don't know how to convert the linked answer from C# to VB? If not why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: I have two pointers for you but no answer: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-33.0/issues/102/unable-geolocation-feature and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348509/how-can-i-get-the-html5-geolocation-feature-to-work-on-geckofx-v22-web-browser-c?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Just Add this Preference. That's it For GeckoFX 45.

```
GeckoPreferences.User("geo.enabled") = True

GeckoPreferences.User("browser.search.geoip.url") = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=GOOGLE MAP API"
```

Comment: Collect Your Google Map API From http://console.cloud.google.com and put the API correctly Like https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key= Your GOOGLE MAP API